# Datepicker changes to default when entering 'mm/dd/yy'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, knockout.js

When a user manually enters or copy/pastes a date that is formatted 'dd/mm/yy' the date picker changes the date entered into the default date.  The format is 'dd/mm/yyyy.'  So when you manually or copy and paste using that format it works.  Is there a utility in moment or a datepicker property that can recognize both dd/mm/yy as well as the dd/mm/yyyy.

view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3" data-bind="uniqueFor: DateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
    <div class="controls col-md-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="uniqueId: DateOfBirth, datepicker: DateOfBirth, datepickeroptions: { readOnly: false, changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, defaultDate: '@DateTime.Today.AddYears(-3).Date', maxDate: '@DateTime.Today', inSessionRequired: false }, disable: $parent.Student.StudentID">
    </div>
</div>
```

knockout:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(js, {
        FirstName: readOnlyMap,
        MiddleName: readOnlyMap,
        LastName: readOnlyMap,
        Suffix: readOnlyMap,
        AlsoKnownAs: readOnlyMap,
        DateOfBirth: {
            create: function (options) {
                return ko.observable(options.data ? moment(options.data).format("L") : undefined).extend({ readOnly: !canUpdateStudent });
            },
            update: function(options) {
                return options.data ? moment(options.data).format("L") : null;
            }
        }
    }, this); 

    self.DateOfBirth.extend({
        date: { onlyIf: requiredIf, message: "Student's date of birth must be a valid date." },
        validation: {
            validator: function (val, max) {
                var date = moment(val);
                return !date.isValid() || date.isBefore(max);
            },
            message: "Student's date of birth cannot be in the future.",
            params: new Date()
        },
        required: { onlyIf: requiredIf, message: "Student's date of birth is required." }
    });
```

Comment: no,what format you specified that only format will be acceptable.

Comment: I did not see the format in your code... Please test this: `MM/dd/yy` For showing mount `m` must be uppercase to avoid conflict with `m : minute`